# If you delete widget from list it reset state of all the widgets below it in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Using floating action button you can add questions, but when you delete particular question it reset state of all the widget below it in the list, everything above it maintains its state. `TextField` didn't retain data though I'm using `TextFieldController`. I'm unable to figure out why this is happening.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kaloory/constants.dart';


class AddQuestionsForTest extends StatefulWidget {
  AddQuestionsForTest({Key key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddQuestionsForTestState createState() => _AddQuestionsForTestState();
}

class _AddQuestionsForTestState extends State<AddQuestionsForTest> {
  int count = 1;
  List<InputWidget> children;

  void removeInputWidget(index){
    setState(() {
      children.remove(index);
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      children = List.generate(count, (int i) => new InputWidget(removeInputWidget, key: ValueKey(i),));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

        appBar: titleAppbar(title: "Create Test"),

        body: Container(
          color: backgroundColor,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: children.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final child = children[index];
              return child;
            },
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: primaryColor,
          splashColor: primaryColor.withOpacity(0.5),
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              children.add(InputWidget(removeInputWidget,key: ValueKey(count),));
              count = count + 1;

            });
          },
        ));
  }

}

class InputWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(InputWidget) removeInputWidget;

  InputWidget(this.removeInputWidget,{Key key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _InputWidgetState createState() => _InputWidgetState();
}

class _InputWidgetState extends State<InputWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 5),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            BuildDropDown(),
            Divider(),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline), onPressed: (){
                widget.removeInputWidget(this.widget);
            })
          ],
        ));
  }
}
class BuildDropDown extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _BuildDropDownState createState() => _BuildDropDownState();
}

class _BuildDropDownState extends State<BuildDropDown> {
  TextEditingController ques = TextEditingController();
  String newValue;
  @override
  Widget build( BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              new ListTile(
                title: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  height: 40,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      border: Border.all()),
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: new DropdownButton<String>(
                        hint: Text('Choose'),
                        onChanged: (String changedValue) {
                          newValue = changedValue;
                          setState(() {
                            print(newValue);
                          });
                        },
                        value: newValue,
                        items: <String>[
                          'Multiple Choice',
                          'Short Answer Type',
                          'Long Answer Type'
                        ].map((String value) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value,
                            child: new Text(value),
                          );
                        }).toList()),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 40,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
          ),
          child: TextField(
            controller: ques,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
              disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: "Untitled Question",
            ),
          ),
        ),
        
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because TextField has it's own internal state, and it's not being saved even though you have assigned a key to the parent.

I think the solution is to save the text value somewhere in the widget state, and in build() check if the contents of the controller.text != _currentText, if they don't match, then inject the last known _currentText.

Comment: Not particularly `TextField` but the whole widget doesn't maintain its state. @shawnblais

Comment: That's odd. As I understand it, same type, same key, it should get the same state, as long as the widget was never totally removed from the tree. Is your key valid?

Comment: That's what I'm doing, removing the whole widget from the List of the widgets.